# The Planes $P_1$ and $P_2$ intersect in the line $L_3$, which has direction $q=(1,a,b)$

Tags: vectors, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

The following is the question I am unable to answer which is the part of a bigger question. The statement goes as follows:

The Planes $P_1$ and $P_2$ intersect in the line $L_3$, which has direction $q=(1,a,b)$; use the relation between $q$ and the respective normal to the planes to find the numbers $a$ and $b$ and hence write the cartesian equation of $L_3$

**Note:** We are given the five points $S,T,U,V,W$ with position vectors $s=(3,1,1)$, $t=(-1,3,2)$, $u=(1,3,0)$, $v=(-1,-3,4)$, $w=(1,5,7)$ at the beginning of question, I don't think they will be of any use in this last part I have confusion in, but I am listing it here, may they are of some use.

**My Working:**

Now, I have solved the remaining parts of the problem and got the following equations of Planes $P_1$ and $P_2$ and their respective normals $n_1$ and $n_2$

$P_1:$ $x+y+z=0$

$P_2:$ $-4x+2y+z=2$

$n_2:$ $(-4,2,1)$

$n_1:$ $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$; $n_1$ is actually unit normal vector that was supposed to be found in the previous parts of this question.

Now I don't know how do I solve using this information for the $a$ and $b$ and the Line $L_3$. Please guide me in this matter. I will greatly appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have swapped $\vec n_1$ and $\vec n_2$.

$ \vec n_1 = (1, 1, 1)$ and $\vec n_2 = (-4, 2, 1)$

Direction vector of the line of intersection of the planes will be orthogonal to normal vectors to the planes.

So to find direction vector of the line $L_3$,

$\vec d = \vec n_2 \times \vec n_1$.

Compare this with the given direction vector of the line $L_3$ making first component equal and that should give you values of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Yeah It was typo. I am gonna edit that. Thanks for your help sir. Also once I have the $a$ and $b$ I will have direction vector of line $L_3$ then how do I find cartesian equation of line from it? Would you take a minute to guide me through it? I will appreciate that too.

Comment: Find a point that is common to both planes - in other words they satisfy equation of both planes. That point is on the line too. So if that point is $(p, q, r)$ then cartesian equation of line is given by $\frac{x-p}{a} = \frac{y-q}{b} = \frac{z-r}{c}$ where $(a, b, c)$ is direction vector of the line.

Comment: Once you are done and you want me to validate your answers, let me know what results you get and I will check.

Comment: That will great. Thank you, I will let you know

Comment: That point is $v=(-1,-3,4).$ The values of $a=5$ and $b=-6$. I have one more question, why we are taking the cross product of $n_2$ with $n_1$ but not vice-versa?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126212/discussion-between-ameer786-and-math-lover).

Answer (score 1):

Since the vector $q$ is parallel to the plane $P_1$, it must be normal to $n_1$, so the dot product $q \cdot n_1$ must be zero. Similarly, $q \cdot n_2 = 0$. You can solve these two equations to get $a$ and $b$.

I don't know what the "cartesian equation" of a line is. You'll need to tell us what form of line equation you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is also the quite interesting method . But I am getting confused. Is my $n_1$ value okay, or will it be $n_1=(1,1,1)$ as written by @Math Lover. because in both cases the answers of $a$ and $b$ are different.

Comment: Changing the length of $n_1$ should not affect $a$ and $b$.